# bzip2 - Bzipping all files inside folders (Windows)

Tags: batch-file, bzip2

I have a bzipping tool on my computer, but it only bzips files that are inside the "compress" directory. How would I make it so files inside all directories inside the compress directory are zipped?

**Example**

> compress/image.png goes to compress/image.png.bz2

however

> compress/folder/image.png stays as compress/folder/image.png

My batch file is as follows:
    @echo off

```
title bzip

echo            bzip
echo All files within /compress will be compressed as a .bz2
echo.
echo Compressing file(s)...

bzip2.exe -z compress/*.*

echo.
echo Compression Completed!
pause
```

I hope somebody can help me!

**Edit:**
When running the process with directories inside the compress directory, it says "permission denied".

Comment: Does the bzip2 help show any `recursion/subdirectory` switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for /r compress %%i in (*) do bzip2.exe "%%i"` in your batch file instead of the call to `bzip2.exe` directly.  bzip2 almost certainly doesn't know how to recurse through subfolders -- standard wildcard globbing libs on Windows generally don't.

Run `for /?` from a Command Prompt to see more about the syntax of the for command.  If you want to test the command from a prompt instead of a batch file, use 1 percent sign for the variable instead of 2.